# Regex repeat group ignoring strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I did some research but nothing worked for my case.

I have this regex where I can get Stream # 0:4 but I would like to repeat the rule and also catch Stream # 0:5. How do I repeat the rule and ignore in the middle `-> # 0: 0 (copy) -> # 0: 1 (copy)`

regex

```
/(?<=Stream mapping:)(\s+)([a-zA-Z])+(\s+)#([0-9]:[0-9])/s
```

text

```
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 800000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

My current result

```
    array(1) { 
[0]=> array(5) 
  { 
  [0]=> string(15) " Stream #0:4" 
  [1]=> string(4) " " 
  [2]=> string(1) "m" 
  [3]=> string(1) " " 
  [4]=> string(3) "0:4" } 
  }
```

Another problem is that my regex is treating "m" as a separate combination and includes empty spaces. How do I fix this?

I wanted a final result like

```
[0]Stream #0:4
[1]Stream #0:5
```

Comment: I am not quite sure, do you need https://regex101.com/r/LP5f9N/2 or https://regex101.com/r/LP5f9N/3?

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/YwonZU

Comment: Although I can not mark the correct answer to my problem. That's what I needed. thank you
 @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a custom word boundary based on the `\G` operator:

```
$re = '/(?:\G(?!^)\s*|Stream mapping:\s*)\K([a-zA-Z]+\s+#[0-9]+:[0-9]+).*/';
$str = 'Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 800000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help';

if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $m)) {
 print_r($m[1]);
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/YwonZU).

Pattern details:

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s*|Stream mapping:\s*)` - either the end of the previous match and 0+ whitespace chars or `Stream mapping:` substring followed with 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` -  match reset operator discarding the currently matched text
- `([a-zA-Z]+\s+#[0-9]+:[0-9]+)` - Group 1: 1+ letters, 1+ whitespaces, `#`, 1+ digits, `:`, 1+ digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars to the end of the line (it must be used since we need continuous matches)

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/LP5f9N/3).

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
/^  Stream #([\d:]+) -> #([\d:]+) \((.*)\)/gm
```

which will match two times,

1. `['0:4', '0:0', 'copy']` and
2. `['0:5', '0:1', 'copy']`

Your look-behind to `(?<=Stream mapping:)` is what broke your approach. I don't think it's really needed for this input.

Note that with the `m` flag, `^` matches on every line, which is useful here.

Comment: There are several streams in the text. I shortened the code in question. I need to get the two Stream they see after "Stream mapping:" as shown in the code.

Comment: Split the text at "Stream mapping" and run the above in a loop. I don't see any reason why using a more complicated regex would improve things. Also, for the future, include your requirements in the question. If you have multiple streams, make your question and your example say so.